# How to create URL parameters from JSON structure in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, get, httpwebrequest

:) For my app I need to generate URL for HTTP GET Request. I've prepared JSON data, because I will be working with them, so I would like to generate these URLs for filtering data from my JSON data structures in C# code.

For example I have this JSON structure:

```
  {
  "filter": {
    "logic": "and",
    "filters": [
      {
        "field": "created",
        "operator": "gte",
        "value": "2016-09-19+00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "field": "created",
        "operator": "lte",
        "value": "2016-09-19+59:59:59"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would like to have this URL:

```
.../api/v6/tickets?filter[logic]=and&filter[filters][0][field]=created&filter[filters][0][operator]=gte&filter[filters][0][value]=2016-09-19+00:00:00&filter[filters][1][field]=created&filter[filters][1][operator]=lte&filter[filters][1][value]=2016-09-19+59:59:59
```

I thought that there could be some method in HttpWebRequest to do that for me, but I didn't find anything. I've tried to pass on JSON data in body, but it's not working (because I need to create Request before that?).

Do you know something (some standardized method or something else) what I could use for generating dynamically URL by JSON structure?

Thank you very much!

Comment: depends on what you need it for, but can't you just urlencode the json string in your querystring? It will probably be much shorter.

Comment: @Jerodev I need it for downloading a content (HttpWebRequest). I've tried WebUtility.HtmlEncode() method to JSON data, but it didn't give me the URL as I needed (in description). I need to add [filters][0] etc or at least I suppose.